# How to convert a Word document into an html file through the chain pandoc -> sphinx and keeping the tabs of the document's code examples

Tags: ms-word, python-sphinx, pandoc, restructuredtext

I would like to create an HTML site from a Word document about Python programming. I use the chain word document -> [pandoc] -> rst file -> [sphinx] -> html site. Everything is working ok except the examples of python code: all the tabs are lost and all the code lines are left aligned which causes the code to be intelligible.

What can I do to solve this problem? I would prefer to act on the original word document than the intermediary restructuredtext file.

How to reproduce the problem (knowledge of word, pandoc, sphinx, restructuredtext  required):

a) build a word document [example.docx] with a python program in it. Python code needs tabs. For example :

Python code example:

```
# ----------------------------------
def affiche(chaine):
    # affiche chaine
    print("chaine=%s" % chaine)


# ----------------------------------
def afficheType(variable):
    # affiche le type de variable
    print("type[%s]=%s" % (variable, type(variable)))


# ----------------------------------
def f1(param):
    # ajoute 10 à param
    return param + 10


# ----------------------------------
def f2():
    # rend 3 valeurs
    return "un", 0, 100


# -------------------------------- programme principal ------------------------------------
# ceci est un commentaire
# variable utilisée sans avoir été déclarée
nom = "dupont"

# un affichage écran
print("nom=%s" % nom)

# une liste avec des éléments de type différent
liste = ["un", "deux", 3, 4]
```

b) with a console, type the following command

```
pandoc -f docx -t rst -i example.docx - t example.rst
```

c) type the following commands:

```
sphinx-quickstart

make html
```

d) the produced html looks like that:

[image: html produced from the word document]

We can see that the lines of the [affiche] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/142gO.png) function are all aligned on the left. That is incorrect for a python code;

Comment: What can we do to reproduce the problem?

Comment: How is _pandoc_ supposed to recognize the parts of the document that are supposed to be code and which are not? Maybe have a look at the [`docx+styles` input format](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#input)...

Comment: apparently, [this is a docx file](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/test/docx/golden/codeblock.docx?raw=true) that pandoc recognizes as containing a code block...

Comment: Images of code are not code. Almost no one, except the very bored, will bother to transcribe images into a reproducible example. Help us to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those interested, i found a solution: i gave to the code, the word style [Source Code] and now the html looks like that :

[image]